Enforce all properties to be certain type
I'm trying to enforce that all properties of an interface to match certain constraints but I'm struggling to get it working properly.
I have a basic interface Field<T> that everything should be wrapped in. I then want to enforce that all properties are either a primitive, an object where all properties are also a Field<T> or a map where the values meet the above 2 constraints.
Here is what I have so far:
interface Field<T> 
{
   value: T;
}

type Primitive = string | boolean | number;

interface IFieldObject
{
    [key: string]: Field<any>;
}

export type NonArrayType<T> = T extends any[] ? never : T;
type FieldMap = Field<Map<any, Field<NonArrayType<Primitive | IFieldObject> | FieldMap>>>;

type FieldProperty = Field<Primitive> | FieldMap | Field<NonArrayType<IFieldObject>>;

export interface State
{
    [key: string]: FieldProperty;
}

And then using it like so:
interface TestObj extends IFieldObject {}

interface CustomState extends State 
{
    a: Field<string>;                  // ok
    b: Field<TestObj>;                 // ok
    c: Field<Map<any, Field<string>>;  // Not Ok
    d: Field<Map<any, Field<TestObj>>; // Not Ok
}

Using any Map gives an error.
For Map<any, Field<string>>, the error is:
Type 'Field<Primitive | FieldedObject | FieldMap>' is not assignable to type 'Field<string>'.
    Type 'Primitive | FieldedObject | FieldMap' is not assignable to type 'string'.
         Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

For Map<any, Field<TempObj>>, the error is similar:
Type 'Field<Primitive | FieldedObject | FieldMap>' is not assignable to type 'Field<Temp>'.
    Type 'Primitive | FieldedObject | FieldMap' is not assignable to type 'Temp'.
         Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FieldedObject'.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
tsconfig
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "composite": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2023"
        ],
        "target": "ES2023",
        "module": "ESNext"
    }
}

Edit:
Forgot to mention that I'm also extending the Map interface and that seems to be what is causing the issue.
declare global 
{
    interface Map<K, V>
    {
        difference: (other: Map<K, V>) => Map<K, V>;
    }
}

Map.prototype.difference = function (this: Map<any, any>, other: Map<any, any>)
{
    const temp = new Map();
    for (let item of this)
    {
        if (!other.has(item[0]))
        {
            temp.set(item[0], item[1]);
        }
    }

    return temp;
}

Any idea how to fix this while keeping the difference function?

"not okay" because... you're repeating the same property in the interface? What happens if you don't use c twice?  Please [edit] to make this a [mre] where it's clear you're not just hitting a typographic error.

@jcalz this wasn't straight copy pasted from code, so that was just a typo. Updated

So you didn't test this in an IDE? Right now if I look at your example in an IDE like the playground I don't see any "not okay" going on. Where is the error exactly? The hope is that your example would be a [mre] where the problem is easily demonstrable to others.

@jcalz, no, I did test it in an IDE and I'm still getting the error. If I paste the exact code above into where I have it now, it gives the errors. If I create a new file and paste it in that file, it doesn't give any error.

So it's... not reproducible then in another environment? Something specific about where you have it now is responsible for the error? I guess we need more debugging details then, since the info you've presented is apparently insufficient to show the issue?

@jcalz added my tsconfig to see if that sheds any light

@jcalz, as soon as I imported the types from the new file that was working into another file, it started erroring like the original. So yea, I guess they work, its just something with the environment.

@jcalz, it looks like turning strict off in the tsconfig removes the errors, but this isn't really a fix

So what can we do here? That tsconfig doesn't seem to be enough for me to reproduce it.  Notice that --strict being on shouldn't be the cause (and it's on here and there's no error). Right now it's still in need of debugging details.

@jcalz found the issue, updated the question

You could make difference's declaration that of a method (as opposed to a function-valued property) as shown in this playground link. That causes type checks to be looser. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining (or find a duplicate). If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz that does fix the issue! I was completely unaware of this. Is there any documentation explaining the differences in type checks for a method declaration vs a function one, or anything similar that mentions this?

To fix your problem, you should change the declaration of difference to be a method as opposed to a function-valued property:
declare global {
  interface Map<K, V> {
    // difference: (other: Map<K, V>) => Map<K, V>;
    difference(other: Map<K, V>): Map<K, V>;
  }
}

interface CustomState extends State {
  a: Field<string>;                  // ok
  b: Field<TestObj>;                 // ok
  c: Field<Map<any, Field<string>>>  // ok
  d: Field<Map<any, Field<TestObj>>> // ok
}

The reason this matters is because TypeScript checks method parameters bivariantly, which is unsafe but very useful, whereas it checks function parameters contravariantly (at least when --strictFunctionTypes is enabled, which happens automatically if you use the --strict suite of compiler options). See Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript for a description of different kinds of variance.

People generally want collections of things to be treated covariantly, meaning that, for example, if Foo extends Bar, people want to be able to use a Foo[] when they need a Bar[].  This is also the case for Maps. People want to be able to use a Map<K, Foo> as a Map<K, Bar>. Indeed, that's what you're doing with your type definitions; you've just presumed that a Map<any, Field<string>> is a FieldMap, because string is a Primitive.  That only works because Map<K, V> is covariant in V.
Unfortunately, it is technically unsafe to allow collections to be covariant, unless those collections are read-only. Array covariance, for all its usefulness, allows dangerous operations like this:
const arr: string[] = ["a", "b", "c"]
function f(arr: Primitive[]) { arr.push(1); }
f(arr); // allowed
arr.map(x => x.toUpperCase()); // runtime error, x.toUpperCase is not a function

Oops, that array of strings got a number pushed into it without TypeScript noticing. So maybe a string[] should not be a valid Primitive[]. That is, maybe arrays should be invariant in their element types. But if we do that then lots and lots of perfectly safe real world code breaks. So it's allowed.
If you look at the TypeScript type declaration for push(), you'll see it's a method and not a function-valued property:
interface Array<T> {
  push(...items: T[]): number; // method
  // push: (...items: T[]) => number; // fn-valued prop
}

If push were declared as a function-valued property, then Array<T> would automatically become invariant in T, since functions are checked the safe strict way, with a covariant parameter. But TypeScript arrays are meant to be covariant, so push is a method.  That's what you need to do with the difference() method of Map, for the same reason.

That's the answer to your question as asked. Your definition for difference caused Map<K, V> to become invariant in V. You'd like to keep it covariant in V, so you change to a method to get looser type checking. But some people are unhappy that this works. There is some controversy around the fact that TypeScript enables technically unsafe operations with collections like Array and Map. Some people would prefer methods to be checked strictly, just like non-method functions.
One major stumbling block to doing that, other than making your life more difficult for the purposes of this question, is that suddenly a lot of built-in class hierarchies are no longer type hierarchies.  Right now if I ask you for a Node you can give me an HTMLElement, but if methods were contravariant, then that wouldn't be allowed, due to the existence of addEventListener(). Which would be weird, since HTMLElement inherits from Element which inherits from Node.  Maybe there'd be some way to fix all these problems, but not without a huge amount of pain in real world code bases.
Before --strictFunctionTypes was implemented, all functions were checked loosely like methods are now. When they implemented, they tried doing that with methods, but quickly ran into the issues mentioned here. So they exempted methods from the stricter checking.  See "Why method bivariance" in the TypeScript FAQ and Why are TypeScript arrays covariant? for more information.
Playground link to code
